# instantiating struct and assigning string but string prints empty line?

Tags: c, struct

I am new to C and I'm trying to instantiate a struct but I'm getting nothing where I would expect a string. My struct is very simple and the string prints correctly at the beginning, until I assign the last value in my struct. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to allocate more space?

Here is what is printed in my terminal

```
before local time is set: node->ip is 127.123.456.789
after local_time is set: node->ip is
```

As you can see, after setting the local time, the string shows blank. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
  char *ip;
  short port;
  int heartbeat;
  int local_time;
};

typedef struct node node;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  node *node = malloc(sizeof(node));

  node->ip = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  memset(node->ip, '\0', INET_ADDRSTRLEN);    
  strcpy(node->ip, "127.123.456.789");

  node->port = 22;
  node->heartbeat = 12;

  printf("before local time is set: node->ip is %s\n", node->ip);
  node->local_time = 11;
  printf("after local_time is set: node->ip is %s\n", node->ip);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is INET_ADDRSTRLEN?

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy its defined as 16

Comment: Can't reproduce.  What compiler / version / settings?

Comment: I'm on a mac osx using this command: `cc -Wall -std=c99 test.c -o bin/test` and cc -v shows:

`Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0 Thread model: posix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shouldn't even compile:
`node *node = malloc(sizeof(node));` You can't have a variable with the same name as a struct.

If you change it to `node *n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` and change the variable 'node' to 'n', it works fine.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand why my compiler let it compile? So odd...

Comment: This isn't quite true; the local `node` identifier shadows the definition of the `node` typedef, as described in C99 §6.2.1/4. I _believe_ what is happening here (but I'm a little fuzzy on this) is that `sizeof(node)` is also referring to the `node` local variable, which is `== sizeof(void*)`, so you're overrunning the buffer when you assign to anything other than `ip`

Comment: @HaldeanBrown ahhhhh that would explain why my linter / compiler is not telling me there is an issue and why i'm having the buffer issue. Thanks for explaining that could happen!

Comment: Interesting that the Visual Studio compiler on windows won't compile as originally written

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy do you have `-Werror` on, maybe? GCC doesn't even have a warning on this program, even with `-Wall` and `-pedantic`